# Customize alert/error message based on the selector which is not selected

Tags: javascript, forms

I have three selectors and currently if anyone of them is not selected, the alert message is "Please fill in the fields".

However, I want to customize the alert.

Suppose out of 3 only 1 selector is not selected - say "dimension" than how can I amend the alert to " Please fill in the field - Two".

My current code is:

```
if (
       checkforNullEmptySelect("group")
    && checkforNullEmptySelect("one")
    && checkforNullEmptySelect("two")
    && checkforNullEmptySelect("three")
) {
    // alert("Values filled in correctly");
    formValid = true
    getData();
    return true;
} else {
    alert(alertMessageArr.correctFields);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "If not the first, show error for it and return false. If not the second, same. If not the third, same. Return true."

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the selector by using "+" operator or `` if you are using es6.

// ES5 ->
alert('Please fill out the fields - ' + selector);

//ES6 -> alert(`Please fill out the fields -  ${selector}`);

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your HTML structure to be as given below:

```
<input  id="one" type="text"/>
<input  id="two" type="text"/>
<input  id="three" type="text"/>
```

Snippet to check fields are empty or not:

```
if(inputOne === 0 && inputTwo === 0 && inputThree === 0){
alert("Please fill all fields");
}else{
 $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {         //Or $(this).length > 0
        alert('all inputs filled');
    }
    else{
        alert('theres an empty input');   //alert selectors if needed
        return false
    }
});
}
```